# Separador para usuario y contraseña - Archivo CSV

Tags: csv, selenium, split, test, test-ng

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, para que cuando ejecute el siguiente caso de prueba, en Username escriba solo: Username, y en Password: Password, y no lo siguiente: Username;Password:

Ejecucion test:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo CSV:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi prueba:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, IOException { 
        driver.get(url);    
        CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] cell;
        String line="";
        String separador=";";

        while((cell=reader.readNext())!=null) {
            String [] nombre=line.split(separador);     
            for(int i=0;i<cell.length;i++) {
                String username=cell[i];
                String password=cell[i]; //con i+1 no lanza el caso de prueba

                driver.findElement(By.id("btn-make-appointment")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys(username);

                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(password);

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn-login']")).click();

            }
        }

    }
```

Creo que debería ser String password=cell[i+1]; pero no lanza la prueba haciéndolo así

Comment: Podrías comenzar el for con i=1, así en primer lugar no obtendrías los valores de los nombre de columna. Después de esto a cada elemento *cell[]* deberías aplicarle la función split, quedandote *cell[0]* como *Username* y *cell[1]* para *Password* .

Comment: También intenté inicializar el for en 1, pero no funciona la prueba. Es curioso, abre la ventana pero no hace el intento de leer "John" y "ThisIsNotAPassword"

Answer (score 0):

En estas lineas deberias usar la variable nombre no cell:

```
String username=cell[i];
String password=cell[i];
// Con variable nombre
String username=nombre[i];
String password=nombre[i+1];
```

De todas formas si tus lineas ya sabes que tienen dos parametros yo no me liaba con otro bucle. Directamente podrias hacer:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys(nombre[0]);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(nombre[1]);
```